# アンドロイド開発で画面下部のボタンの配置方法について

Tags: android-studio, android-layout, android-animation

アニメーションのためのイメージ画像を上部に表示させると、どうしても下部のボタンが右寄りになるのです。layour をcenter にしても中央に来ないのです。プログラミングは素人ですので、できましたらわかりやすくお願いします。参考WEDやコードなどを見せていただければ助かります。F
PS 
layoutの構成が間違っているのか？どうかはわかりません。ただ現状では、どうしてもボタンは画像☆(sun)より右側しか設定できないのです(図１）。図２のようにしたいのです。

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

 <ImageView
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:src="@drawable/sun"
 android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
 android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
 android:layout_marginLeft="153dp"
 android:id="@+id/img"/>

 <LinearLayout
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:orientation="vertical" />

 <LinearLayout
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:orientation="horizontal"
 android:gravity="center"/>

 <Button
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:text="Butt1"
 android:layout_gravity="bottom"
 android:layout_weight="1"
 android:id="@+id/btn1" />
 <Button
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:text="Butt2"
 android:layout_weight="1"
 android:layout_gravity="bottom"
 android:id="@+id/btn2" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

**res/anim/rotate.xml**

```
<rotate
 android:repeatCount="10"
 android:pivotX="10"
 android:pivotY="240"
 android:fromDegrees="0"
 android:toDegrees="360"
 android:duration="500"
 />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

次のようなレイアウトはどうでしょうか？

```
<FrameLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/sun"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/img"/>

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom">

        <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Butt1"
                android:id="@+id/btn1"/>
        <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Butt2"
                android:id="@+id/btn2"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

`FrameLayout` や `LinearLayout` については [mixi-inc/AndroidTraining アプリのレイアウト作成](http://mixi-inc.github.io/AndroidTraining/fundamentals/2.01.create-layout.html) が参考になる思います。

公式なドキュメントはこちらです。
[FrameLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html) 
[LinearLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html)

Comment: frame　layoutでうまくいけました。加えて一つたずねたいのですが、ボタンにandroid:layout_width="wrap_content"            android:layout_height="wrap_content"を使ってますが、ボタンの高さを低くするにはどうすればよいのですか？たとえば”9dp”に代えると表示されないのですが。

Comment: どのように小さくしたいかによるため、はっきり言えないですが、
Buttonは上下に空白を持っているのと、文字の上下にも空白を持っているため、そのあたりの調整も必要になると思います。
また文字を小さくすることでも調整可能だと思います。
詳しい回答が必要でしたら、質問を分けてもらえますか？

Comment: @upanddown2016abc レイアウトについてこの回答で問題なければ、回答のチェックを入れていただけますか？

Comment: チェックしました。ありがとうございますた

Comment: ありがとうございます @upanddown2016abc